# Apt cache master / slave auto negotiation on a local network

Tags: apt, cache

I have 10s of systems on a school network running Ubuntu 18. These systems all regularly update and the impact on the network can be significant.

I've been experimenting with apt-cacher-ng to resolve this problem and it works really well, however it requires that one system is the cache server, which in a school presents problems.

I'm wondering if it's possible to configure the systems to auto negotiate a master cache server on boot? The idea is that the systems boot, one of them declares "i'm master" and starts apt-cacher-ng (and immediately updates), the slaves would then update their proxy settings to point to this machine.

I think that would work to limit the impact of multiple machines updating at the same time, however I can't find a service that does the master/slave negotiation.  The closest I've come would be wackamole which uses the spread toolkit, but it doesn't look quite right (I admit I haven't played with it deeply).

So two questions
 1. would it work (I'm not a sysadmin by profession just learning by tinkering)?
 2. Is there a package that will do the master slave negotiation and allow me to start services accordingly?

Thanks for your help!